# mysql operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

i have two tables named `newlab` and `deadstock` both are in same database
and i want to copy some of the fields of newlab to deadstock for that i am using the follwing code

```
INSERT INTO deadstock
(MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,
Brand,Model,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type) 
SELECT (MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,
Brand,Model_Name,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type)
FROM newlab WHERE PC_Name='".$PC_Name."';
```

but it gives operand should contain one column error

Comment: Get rid of the parenthesis after the `SELECT`.  `INSERT INTO deadstock (MAC,Lab_Code,...) SELECT MAC,Lab_Code,... FROM ...`

Comment: And please read about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
INSERT INTO deadstock
(MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,
Brand,Model,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type) 
SELECT MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,
Brand,Model_Name,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type
FROM newlab WHERE PC_Name='".$PC_Name."';
```